# How to include Bounce of the scroll view also in finding out the direction of the scroll in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I had an application in which i had a web view and some 
headers and bottom views.when i started scrolling the webview  i need 
to find out the direction whether it is to up or down.
I managed to done it by

```
`
      - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{



                if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                {


                    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

                    bottombarview.frame = CGRectMake(0,504,320,45);
                    [UIView commitAnimations];


                }

                else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                {



               [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

                    bottombarview.frame = CGRectMake(0,459,320,45);
                    [UIView commitAnimations];



                }

              self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

            }
    `
```

it is working fine.the problem is when the view bouncing,when the view bouncing it is also working.Can anybody help me on this to include bounce also here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the "dragging" property of UIScrollView to check if the user is currently dragging the content. According to the class reference:

> dragging
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the user has begun scrolling the content. (read-only)

The only problem will be if setting this property to NO is happening after the bounce has finished but it's worth checking.
So your method will look like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.isDragging)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Let us know if this does the job!